# Hex To binary - Using CharAt() with digits and appending numbers in a loop

Tags: loops, binary, append, charat

I am tasked with manually turning Hex codes into binary
I pretty much have it working except that it errors whenever it tries to turn an integer into binary
For example turning HEX number 1, makes it stop
So if i have ABCDEFABC, everythings runs perfectly
If i have ABCDEF123, It stops at F and gives me an 88 for some reason

Any insight would be appreciated

This is my code:

```
    String Hex2="ABCDEF123";


    System.out.println("NEWLOOPTEST");

    StringBuilder hexstring = new StringBuilder();


    for (int x = 0; x <= 8; x++)
    {

    if (Hex2.charAt(x) == 'A')
    {
        hexstring.append(1010);

    }
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == 'B')
    {
        hexstring.append(1011);

    }
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == 'C')
    {
        hexstring.append(1100);
    }
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == 'D')
    {
        hexstring.append(1101);
    }
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == 'E')
    {
        hexstring.append(1110);
    }
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == 'F')
    {
        hexstring.append(1111);
    } 
    //works up to here
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == '0')
    {
        hexstring.append(0000);
    }
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == '1')
    {
        hexstring.append(0001);
    }
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == '2')
    {
        hexstring.append(0010);
    }
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == '3')
    {
        hexstring.append(0011);
    }
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == '4')
    {
        hexstring.append(0100);
    }
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == '5')
    {
        hexstring.append(0101);
    }
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == '6')
    {
        hexstring.append(0110);
    }
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == '7')
    {
        hexstring.append(0111);
    }
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == '8')
    {
        hexstring.append(1000);
    }
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == '9')
    {
        hexstring.append(1001);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("error at char" + x );
    }
    }
    System.out.println("Hex To Decimal is " + hexstring.toString());
```

3994433

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are appending numeric values instead of strings to the StringBuilder. Quote your binary value.

```
String Hex2="ABCDEF123";
System.out.println("NEWLOOPTEST");
StringBuilder hexstring = new StringBuilder();

for (int x = 0; x <= 8; x++)
{
    if (Hex2.charAt(x) == 'A')
    {
        hexstring.append("1010");
    }
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == 'B')
    {
        hexstring.append("1011");
    }
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == 'C')
    {
        hexstring.append("1100");
    }
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == 'D')
    {
        hexstring.append("1101");
    }
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == 'E')
    {
        hexstring.append("1110");
    }
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == 'F')
    {
        hexstring.append("1111");
    } 
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == '0')
    {
        hexstring.append("0000");
    }
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == '1')
    {
        hexstring.append("0001");
    }
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == '2')
    {
        hexstring.append("0010");
    }
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == '3')
    {
        hexstring.append("0011");
    }
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == '4')
    {
        hexstring.append("0100");
    }
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == '5')
    {
        hexstring.append("0101");
    }
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == '6')
    {
        hexstring.append("0110");
    }
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == '7')
    {
        hexstring.append("0111");
    }
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == '8')
    {
        hexstring.append("1000");
    }
    else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == '9')
    {
        hexstring.append("1001");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("error at char" + x );
    }
}

System.out.println("Hex To Decimal is " + hexstring.toString());
```

Comment: You are a beautiful person. It makes sense, and it clicked. Funny how things work sometimes. Thanks you so much, saved me a lot of headache

Comment: @vmina Make sure you fix those binary values that the other post pointed out. I just updated my answer to reflect that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == '3')
{
    hexstring.append(0010);
}
```

For this:

```
else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == '3')
{
    hexstring.append(0011);
}
```

And replace:

```
else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == '7')
{
    hexstring.append(1011);
}
```

For this:

```
else if (Hex2.charAt(x) == '7')
{
    hexstring.append(0111);
}
```

Comment: Oh that was an oversight on my part. Just fixed that, But it doesnt fix my problem. I still get "101010111100110111101111189" as my result. I should instead be getting 101010111100110111101111000100100011. Thanks for that tho!